# ImageJ : Overlay 2 Images When One is Distorted

Tags: overlay, image-manipulation, imagej

I am asking for a step-by-step process with the appropriate plugins (I have been attempting with multipoint and landmark correspondence). Please include images in answer if possible.

I want to overlay two scientific images

The images are not oriented the same due to distortion of the second image from collection at a 45o angle and the object was also at a different orientation (flipped horizontally and slightly rotated)

In Adobe Photoshop I transformed the distorted image to overlay with the
first image by eyeballing the match as you can see below but I am having
difficulty using ImageJ to perform this overlay.  I have been told that my
eyeballing method in Adobe Photoshop will not be sufficient for my methods
section of my manuscript and that I must use a scientific program such as
ImageJ.

I tried to follow instructions from the ImageJ forum for Multipoint and Landmark Correspondence but it does not overlay the two images or transform the second image to match the first. Rather, it distorts a portion of the second image and appears to crop the rest out.

[image: Image link is for my desired overlay product image]

Comment: are the images 2D or 3D?

Comment: 2D. I want to match up object points in the two separate images and overlay them to make a single 2D final image